# Git fetch prune failed remotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, git

My employer has a script that sets up git repositories, but in doing so it adds a lot of remotes that no longer exist. I would like to write a one-liner to prune these remotes.

It seems that the output of `git fetch --all` does include a matchable `Could not fetch <remote>` line, but when I `grep` it, it matches the entire message, not just that line. I have also tried `sed` and `awk`, but to no avail.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Sample output from `git fetch --all`:

```
Fetching <remote>
fatal: '/path/to/remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch <remote>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` isn't matching the entire message. I suspect you tried piping in grep with `| grep`. However, this output is an error message, outputted to stderr, and by using the `|` operator, you only applied grep on stdout. You could use `|&` to `grep` both stdout and stderr. Then, you could use another pipe to  `cut` to extract the problematic repositories. E.g.:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/remotesample (main)
$ git remote -v
remote1 http://example.com/notaremote (fetch)
remote1 http://example.com/notaremote (push)
remote2 http://example.com/alsonotaremote (fetch)
remote2 http://example.com/alsonotaremote (push)

mureinik@computer ~/src/git/remotesample (main)
$ git fetch --all |& grep '^error: Could not fetch'
error: Could not fetch remote1
error: Could not fetch remote2

mureinik@computer ~/src/git/remotesample (main)
$ git fetch --all |& grep '^error: Could not fetch' | cut -d' ' -f5
remote1
remote2
```